# Biber and Biblatex incompatibility after update?

Tags: biblatex, biber, mac

I spent the last couple of hours reading similar questions but couldn't be able to solve my problem.
I am on Mac and have just switched to monterey and updated macPort and Texlive. I did all the update available on Tex Live Utility. Delete the .aux, .bbl and .bcf file of my project and recompile. Now some document that were compiling just fine are not (no bibliography).

When I try to run biber on command line, I get the following error :

```
INFO - This is Biber 2.17
INFO - Logfile is 'myFile.blg'
INFO - Reading 'myFile.bcf'
ERROR - Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.7, expected version 3.8.
This means that your biber (2.17) and biblatex (3.16) versions are incompatible.
See compat matrix in biblatex or biber PDF documentation.
INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

But when I do the following, I see the version 3.17 for biblatex:

```
17:40 [XXX:~]$ tlmgr info biblatex | grep cat-version
cat-version: 3.17
```

I was thinking that maybe I have two version of biblatex somehow but, here what I got when trying to find where biber and biblatex are :

```
17:39 [XXX:~]$ which -a biber   
/Library/TeX/texbin/biber
17:39 [XXX:~]$ kpsewhich -all biblatex.sty
/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
```

If anybody have any clue/idea, I would be more than grateful :)

bye

Comment: check in your log-file which biblatex is actually loaded. Also delete perhaps the bcf and recompile.

Comment: in my log file : 
`(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
Package: biblatex 2020/12/31 v3.16 programmable bibliographies (PK/MW)`
and some lines like 
`Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex custom data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex-dm.cfg' not found.`
Regarding the bcf I already deleted all my temp files and recompiled

Comment: well that is 3.16.

Comment: indeed ... but : how can I update it ? (Tex is telling me `no updates available`) and, additionnaly : why is `tlmgr` telling me that I have 3.17 ?

Comment: No idea, I don't have a mac. Perhaps you have two tex systems. Check the pathes.

Comment: Does TeX Live Utility update a MacPort installation? I know it updates TeX Live installed by MacTeX.

Comment: Well ... I dont really know, I also thought it might be the problem. I might have a macport installation that coexists with a MacTeX one ... I'll try to check

Comment: The most likely explanation is indeed that you have two different TeX systems. Biber and `tlmgr` report from one system while the LaTeX engines and `kpsewhich` come from the other system. This is bound to go wrong. Ideally you would only install TeX in one way. (I hear MacTeX is very popular. But I don't have a Mac, so this is all hearsay.)

Comment: ok, I find some time to remove macport installation and it seemed to have solved the problem ! But I also update my other installation with Tex Live Update (there was a new update today, with biblatex mentioned) .. thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2):

The issue that I had that generated this error was that I had installed mactex via homebrew (`brew install --cask mactex`) and then installed biber  (`brew install biber`). `brew uninstall biber` fixed the issue.